# cant create an array in object on firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have object with 2 string values, 1 int value and 1 array value. And when I add object on firebase, I see strings and int values in database,but not the array. Please, anybody help, how to add object with array value on firebase?

```
public class UploaderActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText ime;
    EditText opis;
    EditText cena;
    Button slikaj;
    Button dodaj;
    ArrayList<Uri> slike=new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> slike2=new ArrayList<>();
    UploadTask uploadTask;

    FirebaseStorage storage;
    StorageReference storageRef;
    StorageReference mountainImagesRef;

    DatabaseReference myRef;

    private FirebaseAuth mFirebaseAuth;
    private FirebaseUser mFirebaseUser;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_uploader);

        mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mFirebaseUser = mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

        storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
        storageRef = storage.getReferenceFromUrl("gs://materialdesign-fb467.appspot.com");

        ime= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ime);
        opis= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.opis);
        cena= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cena);
        slikaj= (Button) findViewById(R.id.slikaj);
        dodaj= (Button) findViewById(R.id.dodaj);


    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(requestCode==1 && resultCode==RESULT_OK && data!=null) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            slike.add(selectedImage);

        }
    }
    public void slikaj(View view){

        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(i,1);



    }
    public void dodaj(View view){

        final ArrayList<Image> images;

        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < slike.size(); i++) {
                Bitmap bitmapImage = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), slike.get(i));
                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bitmapImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, baos);
                byte[] dataBytes = baos.toByteArray();

                String pic = "Image" + i + ".jpg";

                mountainImagesRef = storageRef.child(usernameFromEmail(mFirebaseUser.getEmail())).child(ime.getText().toString()).child(pic);

                uploadTask = mountainImagesRef.putBytes(dataBytes);

                uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                        // Handle unsuccessful uploads
                        Toast.makeText(UploaderActivity.this, "There was an error - please try again!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        // taskSnapshot.getMetadata() contains file metadata such as size, content-type, and download URL.
                        Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
                        Image img = new Image(downloadUrl.toString());
                        Toast.makeText(UploaderActivity.this, downloadUrl.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        slike2.add(img.getUrl());

                    }
                } );
            }

                        //DatabaseReference myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("trails").child(usernameFromEmail(mFirebaseUser.getEmail())).child(trail.getUnique_id()).push();
                        myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Items").child(usernameFromEmail(mFirebaseUser.getEmail())).child(ime.getText().toString()).push();
                        Item item = new Item(ime.getText().toString(),opis.getText().toString(),Integer.parseInt(cena.getText().toString()),slike2);
                        myRef.setValue(item);
                        Toast.makeText(UploaderActivity.this, "Your image has been posted!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    };




    private String usernameFromEmail(String email) {

        if (email.contains("@")) {
            return email.split("@")[0];
        } else {
            return email;
        }
    }
}





public class Item {

    private String name;
    private String desription;
    private int price;
    private ArrayList<String> url;

    public Item(){}
    public Item(String name, String desription, int price, ArrayList<String> url){
        this.name=name;
        this.desription=desription;
        this.price=price;
        this.url=url;
    }
    public Item(String name,String desription,int price){
        this.name=name;
        this.desription=desription;
        this.price=price;

    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDesription() {
        return desription;
    }

    public void setDesription(String desription) {
        this.desription = desription;
    }

    public int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(int price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getUrl() {

        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(ArrayList<String> url) {

        this.url = url;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The upload of the image bytes is performed on a worker thread and takes some time to transfer the data to the Firebase servers.  The `OnSuccessListener` that you use to add URLs to array list `slike2` fires asynchronously, long after this code that follows it executes:

```
Item item = new Item(ime.getText().toString(),opis.getText().toString(),
        Integer.parseInt(cena.getText().toString()),slike2);
myRef.setValue(item);
Toast.makeText(UploaderActivity.this, "Your image has been posted!",
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

The result is that `item` is stored correctly, but does not contain the list of URLs, because `slike2` is empty.

The [Tasks](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Tasks) class provides methods to create a task that completes when a collection of tasks completes.  Consider using those capabilities to rework your code.

Comment: thanks for advice man,but i stil dont know how to do that(i'm begginer)...please,can you show me how to rework my code to use Tasks class ?

Comment: I would be very grateful

Comment: I'll take a look when I have time.  Have you run this code and looked at memory usage?  You can do that using the [Android Monitor](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/android-monitor.html#monitors) in Android Studio.  I think queuing up a number of image uploads is going to take too much memory.  The image byte arrays will be retained until the upload finishes.